# How can I shorten this ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ternary-operator

I have code that stores information retrieved from a database.

Because my JavaScript code is Asynchronous and takes time to retrieve data, I am think it will store errors instead of data.

There is an existing helper function that checks for nested objects up to a high level. I want to make this function shorter and stop the ternary operator from ever returning `''`.

```
const ratingAggregateCount = IsNestedObjectKeyPresent(currentProjectDetails, "ratingAggregate", "count") ? currentProjectDetails.ratingAggregate.count : '';

const ratingAggregateAverage = sNestedObjectKeyPresent(currentProjectDetails, "ratingAggregate", "average") ? currentProjectDetails.ratingAggregate.average.toFixed(1) : '';

const ratingWiseCounts = (!!currentProjectDetails.ratingWiseCounts ) ? currentProjectDetails.ratingWiseCounts : '';
```

Comment: You can shorten `const ratingWiseCounts = (!!currentProjectDetails.ratingWiseCounts ) ? currentProjectDetails.ratingWiseCounts : '';` to `const ratingWiseCounts = currentProjectDetails.ratingWiseCounts || '';`

Comment: @B001 Yes !!true = true
But at first you get either Null or Number and thats not a boolean 
So Example 7 = 7, !7 = false , !!7 = true, used that to get the true or false.

Comment: I want to shortern the Ternary operator like remove the  value : " "  .. that blank string and all

Comment: @AkhilNair A condition in a ternary is treated as a bool any way, `!!` is redundant.

Comment: @estus Ohh! Got it, so (currentProjectDetails.ratingWiseCounts) will be either true or false regardless !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Short-circuit operators **&&**

```
const ratingAggregateCount = IsNestedObjectKeyPresent(currentProjectDetails, "ratingAggregate", "count") && currentProjectDetails.ratingAggregate.count;

const ratingAggregateAverage = sNestedObjectKeyPresent(currentProjectDetails, "ratingAggregate", "average") && currentProjectDetails.ratingAggregate.average.toFixed(1);

const ratingWiseCounts = (!!currentProjectDetails.ratingWiseCounts ) && currentProjectDetails.ratingWiseCounts;
```

example

```js
const a = true && "assign";
const b = "something" && "assign";
const c = false && "not assign";
const d = undefined && "not assign";
const e = null && "not assign";
const f = "" && "not assign";

console.log({a,b,c,d,e,f});
```

Comment: Notice that `(!!currentProjectDetails.ratingWiseCounts ) && currentProjectDetails.ratingWiseCounts` will result in `false` instead of empty string in case it's falsy.

Answer (score 1):

If `IsNestedObjectKeyPresent` helper is mostly used for this purpose, a helper that returns empty string could be used instead:

```
const ratingAggregateCount = nestedObjectKeyOrEmptyString(currentProjectDetails, "ratingAggregate", "count");
```

This is what default value argument in safe navigation functions like [Lodash `get`](https://lodash.com/docs/#get) is for.

There's no need to use a ternary for same value as used in condition, it could be short-circuited:

```
const ratingWiseCounts = currentProjectDetails.ratingWiseCounts || '';
```

In case it's known that the only possibility for a value to be falsy is to be `undefined`, destructuring default value can be used:

```
const { ratingWiseCounts = '' } = currentProjectDetails;
```